# Jenkins Plugin debug breakpoint no work on slave

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am trying to write a plugin which will run on remote jenkins slave, the debugging with breakpoint works fine on the local side, but when I try to debug the job which running on the remote slave, the breakpoints no works anymore.

Can anyone help? what is the root cause worK this is work as design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution finally. Keep using the common remote java application feature. 
Just need to make sure the agent attached.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/oXbi3RhR-Aw